Problem using with_metadata from TonicExporterBuilder
I am using this to build tracer_provider using below code snippet, but it gives me an error while using with_metadata(map). The error says that
found tonic::metadata::MetadataMap but expects tonic::metadata::map::MetadataMap

use opentelemetry::{global, KeyValue, trace::Tracer};
use opentelemetry_sdk::{trace::{self, RandomIdGenerator, Sampler}, Resource};
use opentelemetry_otlp::{Protocol, WithExportConfig, ExportConfig};
use std::time::Duration;
use tonic::metadata::*;

let mut map = MetadataMap::with_capacity(3);

map.insert("x-host", "example.com".parse().unwrap());

let tracer_provider = opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
    .tracing()
    .with_exporter(
        opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
        .tonic()
        .with_endpoint("http://localhost:4317")
        .with_metadata(map)
     )
    .with_trace_config(
        trace::config()
            .with_resource(Resource::new(vec![KeyValue::new("service.name", "example")])),
    )
    .install_batch(opentelemetry_sdk::runtime::Tokio)?;

I am using this dependency in my Cargo.toml
opentelemetry-otlp = { version = "0.17.0", features = ["grpc-tonic"] } 

Below is the error from compiler
pub struct MetadataMap {
note : tonic::metadata::map::MetadataMap is defined in crate tonic : tonic-0.8.3

pub struct MetadataMap {
note : perhaps two different versions of crate tonic are being used here
note : method defined : opentelemetry_otlp tonic-0.12.0

Reference for the above code snippet: https://docs.rs/opentelemetry-otlp/latest/opentelemetry_otlp/

This most certainly is a version mismatch in your dependencies, the compiler likely told you so. Please [edit] in the output of cargo tree and the complete compiler error to confirm this.

@cafce25 Yes, when I ran the build it says , 2 different versions of crate tonic are being used here . So with_metadata which tonic should be used , tonic from opentelemetry_otlp or tonic create. because the tonic version that I am using is 0.11.0 and from otlp it has 0.8 as the version. Can you help on this

Please [edit] your post to contain the output of cargo tree and the complete compiler error

Even though Why is a trait not implemented for a type that clearly has it implemented? talks about traits and them not being implemented, the underlying issue and resolution is the same.

Thanks @cafce25. Indeed there was a mismatch in dependencies. Now whenever I get this type of error I check the cargo tree first
